# In a react app, use a module in a script in the CI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, continuous-integration, ts-node

I have a module that checks if all the environment variables needed in the code are set in a react app.
something simple like this:

```
const getEnvironmentVariable = (key: string): string => {
  if (process.env[key]) {
    return process.env[key] as string
  }
  throw new Error(`Missing mandatory environment variable ${key}`)
}

type Config = {
  foo: string
}

const config: Config = {
  foo: getEnvironmentVariable('REACT_APP_FOO')
}

export default config
```

This does the job when running the app. But It would be clever to run that piece of code in the CI to figure out you are missing before deploying :)

when i try to run it with ts-node, I get the following error:

```
ts-node src/config/environmentVariables.ts
(node:30355) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(...)/src/config/environmentVariables.ts:38
export default config;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Anyone has an idea how to achieve this without tricks like temporary files ?

Regards,
Julien

Comment: Why not compile it to JS and run it with `node`? Are you trying to run your production code in the CI using `ts-node`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I did something like this:

```
// tsconfig.scripts.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "build-script",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["./scripts/validateEnvVars.ts"]
}
```

And in the CI (github actions):

```
      - name: Validate Env Vars
        run: |
          set -o allexport; source .env; set +o allexport
          tsc --project ./tsconfig.scripts.json
          node build-script/scripts/validateEnvVars.js
```

cheers